# Vue Material postinstall failed

Tags: npm, vue.js, vue-material

So I've been working on a Vue.js project for couple times now, and I am facing a problem I've never seen before.

Trying to git pull the project on another computer, or even downloading the project as a zip file, when it's time to `npm install`, vue-material module fails and the whole thing cannot be run.

It goes this way, with vie-material :

`vue-material@1.0.0 postinstall C:\<my_things>\node_modules\vue-material
sh build/git-hooks/install.sh`

Then I see this :

`/usr/bin/bash: build/git-hooks/install.sh: No such file or directory`

Then the modules' tree shows in the terminal, and at the end, I can see all the errors related to vue-material, with this statement :

`Tell the author that this fails on your system:
    sh build/git-hooks/install.sh`

By the way, I tried to crate a brand new Vue project, and tried to add vue-material inside, no problem, so it has to do with my project.

Obviously though, `/usr/bin/bash` does not exist, since I'm running Windows 10.

Any knowledge on npm's installing routine ? I'm out of solution to try...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after couple times figuring out what was wrong, I got this :

I tried to use yarn and it told me that my node version was too old (vue-material needed 7.0+ and my node was 6.9, or at least that is what yarn told me), so I got myself the 8.9.3 node.

After this I tried to use yarn again, and the error with that bash script showed again.... then I just tried to use `npm install` again, and it worked just fine...

I don't know about the bash script thing, but one thing to remember is to always check for node and npm's version when errors happend.... (and yarn looks very cool and simple imo ^^).
You kinda made me think about a version problem though, I got you that ! :D

Problem solved....

Comment: Pierre, would you be willing to take a look at another Vue Material question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59952741/how-to-set-up-flexible-grid-in-vue-material

Answer (score 8):

Can you share your package.json file?
I had this same problem just now and found that NPM could possibly be installing the incorrect version. Where I had "^vue-material": "1.0.0-beta-7" NPM was installing version 1.0.0 instead of 1.0.0-beta-7. If you remove the ^ then it may work for you. This is where I found the answer that helped me.
https://github.com/vuematerial/vue-material/issues/1155